# TileGroup does not fill the container

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I put a TileGroup in a BorderContainer and set the width to 100%, but the content in the TileGroup did not fill the parent container, it leaves a big chunk of blank on the right part.

The code is:

```
 <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:TileGroup width="100%" requestedColumnCount="2">
        <s:Button>
            button1
        </s:Button>
        <s:Button>
            button2
        </s:Button>
        <s:Button>
            button3
        </s:Button>
    </s:TileGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

and the result is like this:

http://i.minus.com/iN39P7Us4cBm1.png

The width is already set to 100% but it does not work.

Is there any way to make the TileGroup fill the container like GridLayout does in Java swing?

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/GridLayoutPane.PNG

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the items are aligned to the left and take up only as much space as they need. To make the items fill up all available space, use the [columnAlign](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TileGroup.html#columnAlign) property and set it to [ColumnAlign.JUSTIFY_USING_WIDTH](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/ColumnAlign.html#JUSTIFY_USING_WIDTH):

```
<s:TileGroup columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth" width="100%"
             requestedColumnCount="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth"
rowAlign="justifyUsingHeight"
```

columnAlign works well, but rowAlign does not work

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer? If it is a question, please open a new question for this an elaborate your exact problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want that your TileGroup has a background color, you should put it inside a BorderContainer, like this:

```
<s:TileGroup width="100%" requestedColumnCount="2">
 <s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="0x373737">
  <s:layout>
    <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="2" verticalGap="2"/>
  </s:layout>
  <s:Button> button1 </s:Button>
  <s:Button> button2 </s:Button>
  <s:Button> button3 </s:Button>
 </s:BorderContainer>
</s:TileGroup>
```

I hope you serve, grettings from Colombia ;)